# Condition for retrieving Cookie through AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I'm new to the cookie. But I think I might have done some wrong with my PHP code. During login process I have a verify login script that verifies the user. And if the user passes it the script will automatically set a cookie, `setcookie("userid", $row["profileId"], time() + 24*3600*14);` and the script also redirects the user to the main page with `header("Location: ../../index.php");` As I'm looking on the network tab in Google Chrome's developer tools, I can see the cookie just for the verify script, both request cookie and response cookie. But why can't see this on all other AJAX request? I can't retrieve the cookies at all, what have I done wrong? I know I have made some common pitfall

The only Cookie I can retrieve is the session cookie. I need the retrieve the cookie using `$_COOKIE` in php. I'm using localhost as the domain

Comment: Whatever the problem is, you are not relying on this cookie for user authentication, right? This would be a major security hole, since cookies can be set on the client side. If setting a cookie {userid: 1} gives the user admin powers, think again about your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are fully automatic. You don't need to grab them in js to send them. The ajax call with automatically send them in the request, you can even set more with the response. But you must be on the same domain for any of this to work. Cross domain cookies are disabled for security.

Answer (score -1):

cookies are client side, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Doesn't I tell them in the server side to set them in the client side. I've learnt that in w3schools

Comment: they are still client side, so if you want to access them with js, do something like above not ajax

Comment: But I need to access them in the server side. So I must retrieve them in javascript document first and then send them in the header as an AJAX call? How do I accomplish that I haven't found any good tutorials yet